# Possible to send specific items from a Jtoken to a list?

Tags: c#, json

For example:

```
"MySwitchInfo": [
    {
      "Id": "11",
      "on": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "13",
      "on": "0"
    },
    {
      "Id": "18",
      "on": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "100",
      "on": "0"
    },
    {
      "Id": "107",
      "on": "1"
    }
  ]
```

I would like to send the Id of only the items where "on" is zero to a list (13 and 100 in the example).

I made a list idList and used:

```
FindAll(f => f["on"].ToString() == "0").ForEach(g => idList.Add(g["Id"].ToString()));
```

but it sends all Id values to the list, not just the two values I want.

If this question has already been asked please direct me to that topic, thanks.

Comment: Deserialize JSON to list, filter, then serialize again. [See this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I best way is to deserialize an object and filter it as objects and not as string. I made a little testing app, that is working as you intended.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string allJsonString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "json1.json"));
        var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(allJsonString);
        // filtering
        deserializedObject.MySwitchInfo = deserializedObject.MySwitchInfo.Where(x => x.on == "0").ToList();
        //deserializedObject.MySwitchInfo <= this is list you are looking for
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject));
    }
}

public class MySwitchInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string on { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<MySwitchInfo> MySwitchInfo { get; set; }
}
```

json1.json contains:

```
{
  "MySwitchInfo": [
    {
      "Id": "11",
      "on": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "13",
      "on": "0"
    },
    {
      "Id": "18",
      "on": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "100",
      "on": "0"
    },
    {
      "Id": "107",
      "on": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

And output is: `{"MySwitchInfo":[{"Id":"13","on":"0"},{"Id":"100","on":"0"}]}`

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json;` for woring with JSON text.